# multi lookup within input

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lookup

I am working on lookup component with multiple selection, as per the design we need to show the selected list and search term both on same component. any inputs to achieve this functionality,  Thanks for the help.
I am following below link but any help appreciate it.

https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc

[image]

Comment: With a few modifications,  my lookup will do this: https://github.com/rapsacnz/MultiSelect

Comment: Thanks @CasparHarmer your component looks great, I guess i need to work on the search implementation..

Comment: Thank you So much, with your component i am able to achieve the functionality, Thanks alot...  @CasparHarmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few modifications, my lookup will do this. Get it [here](http://github.com/rapsacnz/MultiSelect)

Use like this:

```
<c-multi-select label="Authors Assigned" options={authors} onchange={handleAuthorChange}></c-multi-select>
```